# Angular Jasmine "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I changed some code with existing tests and all tests fail now. The change i made was adding the below into ngOnInit(), and getCodeType method.

Ref-action.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {


    this.getCodeType(this.details);
 
}

  getCodeType(_details){
    if(_details.find(({codeType}) => codeType=== "Renew")){
        return (this.codeType= true);
    }
}
```

The .find method has caused all the tests to fail, and shows -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined.

I assume its due to ngOnInit calling the method, but i dont know how to fix that. Angular testing isn't my strong point, i have tried multiple different attempts but i just don't have an idea how to fix it. Thanks:)

ref-action.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(() => {
    testHostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHostComponent = testHostFixture.componentInstance;
    testHostFixture.detectChanges();
    component = testHostFixture.componentInstance.childComponent;
    instance = testHostFixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Even the simple ones such as 'should create' fail, so i feel once i can fix one. Then it should be quick fix to all.

Comment: What is the value of *this.details* in ngOnInit()?

Comment: Its an Array Object.

Comment: Please show the line(s) of code where you declare and initialise *details*.